# How to share a link on Facebook Messenger from other apps?

Tags: xcode, swift, fbsdkmessengersharekit

From [Facebook Developer Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios), I see that I can share image, animated image, even audio clips from other app to Facebook Messenger. But I can see no way to share a link. Neither does when I try to look what kind of share does the FBSDKMessengerShare offer.

[image]

How can I share a link using Facebook Messenger?

Comment: It's weird that it's not possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that it can't be done with FBSDKMessengerShare, but with FBSDKShareKit it's possible. (I'm using Xcode 8.3, Swift 3.1, Cocoapods with FacebookShare 0.2.0)

More info available at
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

There are two methods:

1. Using FBSDKMessageDialog:
   "The Message Dialog switches to the native Messenger for iOS app, then returns control to your app after a post is published."

   ```
   @IBAction func messengerButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

       let linkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
       linkContent.contentURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/someValidAppURL...")

       let dialog = FBSDKMessageDialog()
       dialog.shareContent = linkContent
       dialog.shouldFailOnDataError = true

       if dialog.canShow() {
           dialog.show()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using FBSDKSendButton: "The Send button lets people privately send photos, videos and links to their friends and contacts using the Facebook Messenger. The Send button will call a Message dialog."

   This creates a share button that is displayed in a specified view. The button will be automatically disabled if the Messenger app is not installed on the device.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

       let linkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
       linkContent.contentURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/someValidAppURL...")

       let button = FBSDKSendButton()        
       button.shareContent = linkContent      
       if button.isEnabled { 
          self.view.addSubview(button) 
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The code works, thanks :). But the navigation is not correct 1) On clicking Done button after sharing, the app shows up from first screen 2) On clicking back to app from messenger, it navigates back to the app. But on the next messenger share button click, a blank screen appears, then it navigates back to our app from first screen. Is this an SDK issue?